# Java - Tipos primitivos y tipos por referencia

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo Java y tengo una duda con los tipos de datos.

Una variable de tipo primitivo almacena un único valor. Cuando le asigno uno nuevo, el valor anterior se pierde.

Ahora con las variables por referencia planteo un ejemplo, tengo una clase llamada `Auto`, con una variable de instancia, llamada `Color`.

Si creo dos objetos de esa clase, ambos apuntarían "a lo mismo" en la memoria, pero cada uno mantendría una copia individual de la variable de instancia, por lo cual puedo cambiar el valor de Color en un objeto, sin que afecte al otro.
Sin embargo, si destruyo el objeto, las referencias de ambos se perderían (Supongo que volverían a apuntar a `null`).

¿Este concepto que tengo es correcto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para complementar la [buena respuesta de @NaCl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16256/227), creo que esta parte queda como duda:

> Ahora con las variables por referencia planteo un ejemplo, tengo una clase llamada Auto, con una variable de instancia, llamada Color.
>
> Si creo dos objetos de esa clase, ambos apuntarían "a lo mismo" en la memoria, pero cada uno mantendría una copia individual de la variable de instancia, por lo cual puedo cambiar el valor de Color en un objeto, sin que afecte al otro. Sin embargo, si destruyo el objeto, las referencias de ambos se perderían (Supongo que volverían a apuntar a null).

Diseñemos las clases `Auto` y `Color`:

```
//diseñada como inmutable puesto que un color no puede cambiar
public class Color {
    private final String name;
    public Color(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String toString() { return getName(); }
}

public class Auto {
    private int year;
    private Color color;
    //constructor vacío
    //getters y setters para la clase
}
```

Solo puedes crear nuevas instancias de un objeto mediante la palabra `new`. Al crear dos instancias mediante el uso de `new` y asignarlas a diferentes variables, las variables apuntarán a lugares de memoria distintos. Esto se puede ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si utilizamos la misma instancia de `Color` en ambas instancias de `Auto`, el resultado será como sigue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambiaras el valor de color en otro de ellos, solo el otro se vería afectado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que quiere decir usar la misma instancia de Color en cada una de las instancias de Auto? Mil disculpas por estas preguntas, recién comienzo y se me está complicando la POO.

Comment: Como puedes ver en la imagen, solo se crea una variable de tipo `Color` y solo existe una instancia (una sola vez que se ha usado `new Color`). Esta instancia se almacena en la variable `verde` y es la que se utiliza en el `setColor` de ambas instancias de auto. Las imágenes tienen en la parte izquierda el Heap que es la memoria que utiliza Java para almacenar las instancias de las variables (es decir, cuando te refieres a la RAM, en Java estaríamos hablando de Heap).

Comment: Ahora si, muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: con que hiciste las imagenes @LuiggiMendoza?

Comment: @jasilva con paint, me tomó un poco de tiempo

Answer (score 2):

Cuando usas un tipo primitivo, al asignarle un valor, el valor anterior se "sobreescribe", así que sí, literalmente se pierde, porque los valores variables pueden cambiar en cualquier momento.

Cuando trabajas con objetos, por ejemplo, digamos que tienes la clase `Auto`:

```
class Auto
{
    // ...
}
```

Y le asignas una nueva instancia:

```
Auto Toyota = new Auto(2005, "Camry"); // Año y Modelo
```

Tienes un nuevo auto colocado en memoria, si hacemos lo siguiente:

```
Auto OtroToyota = Toyota;
```

La nueva variable `OtroToyota` apunta a la referencia de la nueva instancia que creamos anteriormente, lo que hace que al cambiar algún valor en cualquiera de las instancias, este valor se cambie en todas las referencias que tengas hacia ese objeto, ejemplo:

```
Toyota.Modelo = "Corolla"; 
System.out.print(OtroToyota.Modelo); // Debe imprimir "Corolla"
// O por lo menos este es el comportamiento estimado en C#, en Java debe parecerse.
```

Así que sí, tu concepto es cierto hasta el punto de que apuntas a la instancia definida con la palabra clave `new`. Si asignas `null` a uno de los 2, el otro *(Y todos los demás apuntadores hacia esa instancia)* se verán afectados.

Vease la siguiente implementación como ejemplo:

```
public class Auto {
    // Implementación de la clase Auto (ejemplo):
    public int Year;
    public Auto(int y) { Year = y; }
}

public static void main(string []args) {
    Auto Camry = new Auto(1994);
    Auto Toyota = Camry;
    System.out.println(Camry.Year);  // Imprime 1994
    Toyota.Yr = 1995;
    System.out.println(Camry.Year);  // Imprime 1995
    System.out.println(Toyota.Year); // Imprime 1995
}
```

Entonces, tu respuesta finalmente resumida es "Sí", pero no se mantienen "copias" de las instancias en punteros *(O por lo menos eso tengo entendido)*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me aclaraste bastante. Una última duda. Si yo tengo, como puse en el primer post, dos objetos diferentes creados mediante el operador new, en memoria apuntan al mismo objeto, pero las variables de instancia son independientes una de otra?

Comment: Ok. Ahí publiqué un comentario con una última duda. Ahí la marco como aceptada, muchas gracias.

Comment: Oh, no lo había visto. Pues no, al definir una nueva instancia con el operador `new` estas no estan _"enlazadas"_ por lo que si eliminas una, la otra no se ve afectada ya que no comparten el mismo espacio en memoria.

Comment: Ahora si, esa era mi duda. Muchas gracias.