# ¿Es posible que un objeto en java se modifique sin especificarlo en el código?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un programa que resuelve [sokoban](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) con el algoritmo de búsqueda a lo ancho (BFS) Y un atributo de un objeto se modifica en el código y en ningún momento le estoy haciendo una asignación o un set.

[image: Consola]

El código que genera lo de arriba es el siguiente:

```
private Nodo getHijo(Nodo nodopadre, String accion){
    int nuevocosto = nodopadre.getCosto()+1;
    System.out.println("Nodo Padre con accion: "+accion);
                imprimirEstado(nodopadre.getEstado());

    String nuevoestado[][]=nodopadre.getEstado();
    //Encontrar al jugador en el estado
    int filajugador=0;
    int columnajugador=0;
    for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
            if(nodopadre.getEstado()[x][y].equals("@")){
                filajugador=x;
                columnajugador=y;
            }
        }
    }

    if(accion.equals("arriba")){
        //Mover la caja en caso de que el jugador la mueva
        if(nodopadre.getEstado()[filajugador-1][columnajugador].equals("$")){
            nuevoestado[filajugador-2][columnajugador]="$";
        }
        //mover al jugador
        nuevoestado[filajugador][columnajugador]=" ";
        nuevoestado[filajugador-1][columnajugador]="@";


    }
    if(accion.equals("izquierda")){
        //Mover la caja en caso de que el jugador la mueva
        if (nodopadre.getEstado()[filajugador][columnajugador - 1].equals("$")) {
            nuevoestado[filajugador][columnajugador - 2] = "$";
        }
        //mover al jugador
        nuevoestado[filajugador][columnajugador] = " ";
        nuevoestado[filajugador][columnajugador - 1] = "@";


    }
    if(accion.equals("abajo")){
        //Mover la caja en caso de que el jugador la mueva
        if (nodopadre.getEstado()[filajugador + 1][columnajugador].equals("$")) {
            nuevoestado[filajugador + 2][columnajugador] = "$";
        }
        //mover al jugador
        nuevoestado[filajugador][columnajugador] = " ";
        nuevoestado[filajugador + 1][columnajugador] = "@";


    }
    if(accion.equals("derecha")){
        //Mover la caja en caso de que el jugador la mueva
        if (nodopadre.getEstado()[filajugador][columnajugador + 1].equals("$")) {
            nuevoestado[filajugador][columnajugador + 2] = "$";
        }
        //mover al jugador
        nuevoestado[filajugador][columnajugador] = " ";
        nuevoestado[filajugador][columnajugador + 1] = "@";


    }
    System.out.println("Nodo hijo");
                imprimirEstado(nuevoestado);


    System.out.println("Nodo padre de nuevo");
    imprimirEstado(nodopadre.getEstado());
    Nodo nuevonodo=new Nodo(nuevoestado, nodopadre, nuevocosto, accion);
    return nuevonodo;
}
```

Clase Nodo

```
public class Nodo {
    private Nodo padre;
    private String[][] estado;
    private int costo;
    private String movimiento;

    public Nodo(String[][] estado, Nodo padre, int costo, String movimiento){
        this.estado=estado;
        this.padre=padre;
        this.costo=costo;
        this.movimiento=movimiento;
    }

    public Nodo getPadre() {
        return padre;
    }

    public void setPadre(Nodo padre) {
        this.padre = padre;
    }

    public String[][] getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String[][] estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public int getCosto() {
        return costo;
    }

    public void setCosto(int costo) {
        this.costo = costo;
    }

    public String getMovimiento() {
        return movimiento;
    }

    public void setMovimiento(String movimiento) {
        this.movimiento = movimiento;
    }
}
```

---

> No entiendo que está pasando. Es algo en este bloque de código, pero aún no comprendo qué
>
> ```
> if(accion.equals("arriba")){
>         //Mover la caja en caso de que el jugador la mueva
>         if(nodopadre.getEstado()[filajugador-1][columnajugador].equals("$")){
>             nuevoestado[filajugador-2][columnajugador]="$";
>         }
>         //mover al jugador
>         nuevoestado[filajugador][columnajugador]=" ";
>         nuevoestado[filajugador-1][columnajugador]="@";
>
>
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que el nodo padre e hijo comparten el mismo estado. Al modificar el estado de uno, también modificas el del otro.

Comprueba las siguientes líneas de tu código:

```
String nuevoestado[][]=nodopadre.getEstado();
// ...
Nodo nuevonodo=new Nodo(nuevoestado, nodopadre, nuevocosto, accion);
return nuevonodo;
```

Al crear un nuevo nodo, le estás asignando el mismo `String[][]` porque la variable `nuevoestado` es una referencia al array del nodo padre. Seguramente, al crear un nuevo nodo lo que deberías hacer generar una copia del estado en vez de usar el mismo.

En la pregunta ["Java - Tipos primitivos y tipos por referencia"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16250/java-tipos-primitivos-y-tipos-por-referencia) puedes encontrar una buena explicacón sobre referencias en java.

Comment: Gracias, no tenía idea que cuando se usaba el operador "=" con objetos pasaba eso

Answer (score 1):

Los objetos de tipo Nodo a los que llamas "padre" e "hijo", son en realidad la misma instancia, de modo que al modificar a uno, ves al otro también modificado.

Comment: No son la misma instancia de `Nodo` puesto que para crear al hijo está haciendo `Nodo nuevonodo = new Nodo(...)`. Parde e hijo son instancias diferentes de `Nodo` cuyos atributos `estado` hacen referencia a la misma instancia de `String[][]`.