# Lista Simplemente Enlazada Java

Tags: java, lista

Estoy desesperado por encontrar ayuda sobre las listas enlazadas en java; ya he buscado por todos lados ejemplos, videos, ya lei un par de libros y no consigo comprender como funcionan. Lo que principalmente no comprendo es en DONDE se están guardando los nuevos elementos de la lista que se van agregando, en variable inicio o en variable fin

clase 1

```
package prueba.lista;

public class Lista {

Nodo inicio;
Nodo fin;

    public Lista()
    {
        inicio = null;
        fin = null;
    }

    public void InsertarFinal( String info)
    {
        Nodo nuevo = new Nodo( info, null);

        if (inicio == null)
        {
            fin = nuevo;
            inicio = nuevo;
        }

        else 
        {   

            fin.setSiguiente(nuevo);  <-------------------------------------
            fin = nuevo;  // esta es la linea de codigo que no comprendo,  ^
                          //porque al asignarle nuevo a fin, a mi parecer  |
                          //se borra lo que estaba en fin anteriormente y  |
                          //ahora tendria unicamente nuevo; y la linea     |
                          //anterior de codigo           ----------------->
                          //no seriviría de nada porque la variable fin
                          //se sobreescribío completamente
        }
    }

    public void Mostrar()
    {
        Nodo temp = inicio;    //esto es lo otro que no entiendo, donde se 
                               //guardaron todos los elementos? en variable inicio?
                               //como es eso posible? la unica vez que se le 
                               //asignó algo a variable inicio es cuando se 
                              // validaba que era null, entonces se le asignaba
                              // el primer elemento de la lista
        while( temp != null)
        {
            System.out.println( temp.getInfo() );
            temp = temp.siguiente;
        }
    }
}
```

clase 2

```
package prueba.lista;


public class Nodo {

    private String info;
    Nodo siguiente;

    public Nodo( String i, Nodo s)
    {
        info = i;
        siguiente = s;
    }


    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }


    public void setSiguiente(Nodo siguiente) {
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
    }


}
```

Clase 3

```
package prueba.lista;

public class PruebaLista {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lista l1 = new Lista();

        l1.InsertarFinal("a");
        l1.InsertarFinal("b");
        l1.InsertarFinal("c");
        l1.InsertarFinal("d");

        l1.Mostrar();
    }

}
```

ayuda por favor :(

Comment: `fin = nuevo` reemplaza la *referencia* que `fin` tenía, no el objeto `Nodo` en sí. El objeto al que refería `fin` sigue existiendo y no cambia.  Para entender esto, necesitas captar como funcionan las referencias a objetos en Java. Tal vez esto te ayude: [Java - Tipos primitivos y tipos por referencia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16250/java-tipos-primitivos-y-tipos-por-referencia).

Comment: Gracias, eso responde muchas cosas.  Pero eso quiere decir tambien que en realidad cada elemento de la lista NO es un objeto sino una referencia? y en mi programa en donde se estan guardando dichas referencias?

Comment: La clave es la referencia `inicio` que es una referencia que apunta al primer elemento de la lista.  Luego, cada elemento `Nodo` tiene una referencia que apunta al siguiente elemento por medio de la variable `siguiente`. Es una cadena. El método `Mostrar` lee esa cadena a partir de `inicio` y a través de las referencias `siguiente` hasta que llega al último elemento.

Comment: Las listas simplemente enlazadas siguen el siguiente principio: un nodo contiene su valor y una referencia al siguiente nodo. En el caso del ultimo nodo (fin) la referencia al siguiente es `null` y cuando se añade un nuevo elemento se crea un nodo, la referencia al siguiente de fin se cambia al nuevo nodo y este pasa a ser el fin.

Answer (score 3):

Visualiza tu estructura así:

```
Inicio-->Nodo1(sig)-->Nodo2(sig)-->Nodo3(sig)<--Fin
```

Tienes dos punteros, *inicio* y *fin*.

- **inicio** apunta a tu primer nodo
- **fin** apunta al ultimo nodo agregado, y se actualiza cada vez que se agrega un nuevo nodo

En el ejemplo arriba `fin` apunta a Nodo3. si llamamos a `InsertarFinal`, se crea un nuevo nodo, Nodo4, este nodo se agrega a Nodo3 (el nodo a que apunta `fin` en este momento) como siguiente, y finalmente se cambia la **referencia** de `fin` a Nodo4 para de nuevo apuntar al ultimo nodo. El resultado es:

```
Inicio-->Nodo1(sig)-->Nodo2(sig)-->Nodo3(sig)-->Nodo4(sig)<--Fin
```

En `Mostrar` se crea un puntero `temp` apuntando al primer nodo, Nodo1. Luego de imprimir el info del nodo, se revisa si el nodo tiene un nodo siguiente. Para Nodo1 eso es Nodo2. Entonces se cambia el puntero `temp` al nodo siguiente (Nodo2), repitiendo el proceso hasta que se llega a Nodo4, que no tiene ningun nodo siguiente asignado.

Answer (score 1):

Las listas simplemente enlazadas siguen el siguiente principio: un nodo contiene su valor y una referencia al siguiente nodo. En el caso del último nodo (fin) la referencia al siguiente es null y cuando se añade un nuevo elemento se crea un nodo, la referencia al siguiente de fin se cambia al nuevo nodo y este pasa a ser el fin